# Problema com mensagem de success apos cadastro de 2 inputs no banco!

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js

Ola, estou com um problema no meu codigo, apos fazer o cadastro de 2 inputs deverai aparecer uma mensagem de sucesso em uam div verde, porem so aparece a div verde e a mensagem não, ja revisei o codigo varias vezes e ainda nao encotrei o erro (provavelmente deve ser algum erro bobo mas infelizmente nao consigo achar), obrigado pela ajuda!!

Segue abaixo o codigo:

App.js:

```js
// Carregamento de modulos
    // Constante que recebe o express
        const express = require('express');
    // Constante que recebe o handlebars
        const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
    // Constante que recebe o bodyparses
        const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    // Constante que recebe o mongoose
        const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    // Constante que recebe a função do express
        const app = express();
    // Constante para chamar rotas de um arquivo externo (usar nome do arquivo no nome da constante)
        const admin = require('./routes/admin.js');
    // Constante para receber modulo de arquivos estaticos e trabalhar com diretorios
        const path = require('path');
    // Constante pare receber o modulo session
        const session = require('express-session');
    // Constante para  receber o modulo flash
        const flash = require('connect-flash');

// Configurações
    // Configuração das sessões
        app.use(session({
            // Chave para gerar uma sessão 
            secret: 'root',
            resave: true,
            saveUninitialized: true
        }));
    // Configuração da sessão flash
        app.use(flash());
    // Middleware
        app.use((req, res, next) => {
            // Comando 'locals' para criar variaveis globais
            res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
            res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
            // Comando 'next();' para permitir que as rotas avancem apos passarem no mdidleware
            next();
        });
    // Configuração do BodyParser
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
        app.use(bodyParser.json());
    // Configuração do HandleBars
        app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
        app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
    // Configuração do Mongoose
        mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
        mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/blogapp', {useNewUrlParser: true}).then(() => {
            console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('Error to connect: ' + err);
        });
    // Configuração do caminho (Path) na pasta public
        app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Rotas
    // Comando para chamar um grupo de rotas em um arquivo especifico
        app.get('/', (req, res) => {
            res.send('Index Route!');
        });

        app.get('/posts', (req, res) => {
            res.send('Post Lists!');
        })

        app.use('/admin', admin);

// Outros
    // Constante da porta localhost
        const PORT = 8081;
    // Função para abrir o servidor na porta selecionada
        app.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log('Server running!');
        })
```

admin.js:

```js
//Carregamento de modulos
    // Constante que recebe o express
    const express = require('express');
    // Constante para cirar rota em arquivo externo
    const router = express.Router();
    // Constante que recebe o mongoose
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    // Comando para chamar o path 'models'
    require('../models/Category');
    // Constante para importar o arquivo Category.js com os comandos do mongo da pasta 'models'
    const Category = mongoose.model('categories');

    // Rota principal para o painel administrativo
        router.get('/', (req, res) => {
            res.render('admin/index')
        });
    // Rota para listar posts
        router.get('/posts', (req, res) => {
            res.send('Post page!');
        });
    // Rota para cadastrar categorias
        router.get('/categories', (req, res) => {
            res.render('admin/categories');
        });
    // Rota onde são adicionadas as categorias
        router.get('/categories/add', (req, res) => {
            res.render('admin/addcategories');
        });
    // Rota onde as categorias adicionadas aparecem
        router.post('/categories/new', (req, res) => {
            // Validação do formulario (manual)
            var error = []
            // Verificação do campo nome: vazio, indefinido ou nulo
            if (!req.body.name || typeof req.body.name == undefined || req.body.name == null){
                // Comando push para colocar um novo dado dentro do array
                error.push({text: 'Invalid name'});
            }
            // Verificação do campo slug: vazio, indefinido ou nulo
            if (!req.body.slug || typeof req.body.slug == undefined || req.body.slug == null){
                error.push({text: 'Invalid slug'});
            }

            // Verificação da quantidade de caracteres inseridos do nome
            if (req.body.name.length < 2){
                error.push({text: "Name of category too short"});
            }
            // Verificação de erros de acordo com o array, se error for maior que 0, houveram erros
            if (error.length > 0){
                res.render('admin/addcategories', {error: error})
            // Se o array for < ou = 0, os dados são inseridos no banco
            } else {
                const newCategory = {
                    // Comando para pegar o input do <form> com o 'name' = name
                    name: req.body.name,
                    // Comando para pegar o input do <form> com o 'name = slug
                    slug: req.body.slug
                };
                new Category(newCategory).save().then(() => {
                    // Comando flash para chamar a variavel global 'success_msg' caso tenha sucesso ao cadastrar o formulario
                    req.flash("success_msg", "Successfully created category!");
                    // Redirecionamento para a pagina 'categories'
                    res.redirect('/admin/categories')
                }).catch((err) => {
                    // Comando flash para chamar a variavel global 'error_msg' caso ocorra um erro ao cadastrar o formulario
                    req.flash("error_msg", "There was an error registering the category, please try again!");
                    // Redirecionamento para pagina 'admin' caso aconteça um erro
                    res.redirect('/admin');
                })
            }
        })

// Exportação final para sincronizar as rotas (esse comando sempre devera ficar no final do codigo!)
    module.exports = router
```

main.handlebars:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- Comando para linkar o html com o CSS do Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Blog NodeJS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Comando para importar um arquivo .handlebars externo -->
    {{>_navbar}}
    <div class="container mt-4">
        <!-- Comando para chamar as variaveis globais de mensagem de erro -->
        {{>_msg}}
        <!-- Comando para chamar o body direto do framework handlebars  -->
        {{{body}}}
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/js/bootrstrap.js"></script>
</html>
```

addcategories.handlebars:

```html
{{#each error}}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{text}}</div>
{{else}}

{{/each}}
<h3>New category: </h3>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
    <form action="/admin/categories/new" method="POST">
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Category name" class="form-control">
    <label for="slug">Slug: </label>
        <input type="text" id="slug" name="slug" placeholder="Slug of category" class="form-control">
        <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create cateogry</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

_msg.handlebars:

```html
{{#if success_msg}}
    <!-- Div para exibir mensagem de sucesso ao cadastrar formulario -->
    <div class="alert alert-success"{{success_msg}}></div>
{{/if}}

{{#if error_msg}}
    <!-- Div para exibir mensagem de erro ao cadastrar formulario -->
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{error_msg}}</div>
{{/if}}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

O erro está no _msg.handlebars:

```
{{#if success_msg}}
    <!-- Div para exibir mensagem de sucesso ao cadastrar formulario -->
    <div class="alert alert-success"{{success_msg}}></div>
{{/if}}

{{#if error_msg}}
    <!-- Div para exibir mensagem de erro ao cadastrar formulario -->
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{error_msg}}</div>
{{/if}}
```

Na parte {{success_msg}}, observe que a mensagem está sendo setada como um atributo html. Altere para:

```
<div class="alert alert-success">{{success_msg}}</div>
```